# addition in bash with decimal using bc

Tags: bash

I'm new in bash and i'd like to know why my script doesn t work the way i'd like it work..

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read n

var=($(cat))

bim=${var[*]}

toto=$(echo $bim | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc)

echo $toto

bobo=$(($toto/$n | bc -l))

echo $bobo | awk '{printf "%.3f\n", $1}'
```

This is supposed to add up all the values that "cat" has stored in an array and divide the total by the first value that "read" reads. And the result should return me a decimal value of three decimal places. However, it only returns a round number to me when I use `bc -l`! And when I use `awk '{printf% .3f ", $ 1}'` it prints `.000`!

Do you know why?
Thanks

Comment: What values do you input? `the result should return me a decimal value of three decimal places` For what input? Why?

Comment: please update the question with the sample input, the (wrong) output generated by your script, and the (correct) desired output; after the `var=($(cat))` add `typeset -p var` and update the question to include the output from this command

Comment: @Mo. : Your `read` consumes one line from stdin and stores it into `n`. Your `cat` then consumes the remaining stdin and stores it into `var`. While I don't understand what you want to achieve with this, you need to tell us at least how you invoke your program, since the behaviour obviously depends on its standard input.

Comment: @ user1934428 It was just an exercice from the hackerrank.com since i'm trying to improve my bash skills (and python as well) I do multiple exercice, you can check the problem here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---compute-the-average/problem

Answer (score 0):

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) only does integer arithmetics and the arithmetic expansion

```
bobo=$(($toto/$n | bc -l))
```

will not do what you think. The pipe sign in `| bc -l` is not a pipe sign. It's a bitwise `OR`. Broken down:

- `$toto` is interpreted as a variable (as would `toto`)
- `$n` is interpreted as a variable (as would `n`)
- `|` is bitwise `OR`
- `bc` is interpreted as a variable (with the value `0`)
- `-` is interpreted as a *minus* sign (in an arithmetic expression)
- `l` is interpreted as a variable (with the value `0`)

So, it becomes `$toto/$n | 0 -0` which is the same as the integer division `toto/n` (`$` is not needed for variables in arithmetic expansions).

You could instead use `bc` for the division too, but you need to set the `scale` in `bc`. Here's an example setting it to `3` before performing the division:

```
bobo=$(echo "scale=3;$toto/$n" | bc)
```

Note that you don't need to `echo` this through `awk`.
Just `echo $bobo` and you should get the result you want.

Example input:

```
3
11.3
9
8
```

Output after having applied the suggested changes:

```
28.3
9.433
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying to improve my bash skills and thank to you I understood that scale can be used with bc and now it's working! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mo. Great, you're welcome! I made the explanation a little more verbose. I hope that helps making it a bit more clear.